# Getting numbers of rows in SUMIF range from different cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sum, excel-indirect

I use a SUMIF function of the kind:

```
=SUMIF('Sheet1'!D54:D63, "QueryText", 'Sheet1'!J54:J63)
```

My problem is that the ranges D54:D63 and J54:J63 will change so I want to get the number of rows from some other cell. 
e.g. In cell A1 I would have `54`, in cell A2 I would have `63` and my formula should be:

```
=SUMIF('Day by day results'!D(VALUEOF(A1)):D((VALUEOF(A2)), "Day Game", 'Day by day results'!J(VALUEOF(A1)):J(VALUEOF(A2)))
```

Obviously the `VALUEOF(A1)` does not work there, that's just for the example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: Can you reference a named range instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&A1&":D"&A2),"QueryText",INDIRECT("Sheet1!J"&A1&":J"&A2))
```

Answer (score 1):

@pnuts solution will work. But for a nonvolatile alternative you can use this:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,A1):INDEX(Sheet1!D:D,A2), "QueryText", INDEX(Sheet1!J:J,A1):INDEX(Sheet1!J:J,A2))
```

A volatile formula is one that recalculates on any change to the worksheet it resides in, regardless of whether the references it uses have changed or not. The INDIRECT() function is volatile in all cases. The INDEX() function is not.